# Limit user mailbox size

Tags: webmin, virtualmin

I have a Webmin postfix server and one of my clients has a mailbox that exceeds 4GB. Their default user plan should only allow them to have 1024MB of data in all their mailboxes combined, however, this doesn't seem to be the case.

I have found a webmin module that is called "Disk quota" but I'm not sure what would happen if I enable the quota.

Comment: Enabling the disk quota will allow you in restricting the disk size of domain if user uses the size more than it was assigned to it, his/her domain will be suspended automatically.

Comment: Do I have to set manual limits or are the limits set by the plan they are on enough?

Comment: You need to create different plans lets say for 1GB, 5GB or any and you just need to assign the plans to the different users as per their requirements or you can either set this manually also.

Comment: The default plan was already at 1024MB but the disk quota module was turned off. I turned it on and it showed the quotas for the domain as "unlimited" after checking the "Check group limits" page. I created a bigger hosting plan (5GB) and put my client on that one, hopefully the disk quota will warn them once they exceed 5GB.

Comment: you may modify the account settings for this user or create one new plan of 1024 MB with disk quota module turned on and add this new plan for this user by replacing previous one.